# Stimulsoft Server ERROR Access to the path 'Stimulsoft' is denied

Tags: windows, iis, stimulsoft

I install Stimulsoft Server in Windows Server 2019 IIS but all url are Access denied except the main route.

for example http://localhost:40010/designer and all report url Access denied.

this is my error in browser

> Access to the path 'Stimulsoft' is denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled
> exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
> Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
> where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
> path 'Stimulsoft' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
> granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
> identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
> {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
> the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
> the application is not impersonating. If the application is
> impersonating via , the identity will be
> the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
> request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
> Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
> to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
> and check the boxes for the desired access.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is obvious, iis does not have permission to access the Stimulsoft, you can try the following steps to solve the problem:

- Go to wwwroot folder. Right-click and security tab. Provided `IISUSER` to set read and write permission to the wwwroot folder.
- Right click the application pool and select Advanced Settings. Select the Identity list item and click the ellipsis (the button with the three dots). The following dialog appears: Select the Built-in account button, and then select the identity type `ApplicationPoolIdentity` from the combo box.